# How to project screen in android x86

Tags: screen, android-x86, android-pc

I have installed Windows as well as android x86 on my laptop. Everything was just fine until the LCD of my Laptop was not broken. Now with broken screen I use Specific key combination to project my screen to an external monitor. This feature works fine with Windows but the key-combination does not work for android x86. Monitor does not even detect a signal from laptop. Is there any trick to project the screen in android with parent screen broken?

Answer (score 0):

Just find your grub configuration file of android-x86 operating system and add **`video=LVDS-1:d`** to the end.

This will enable external monitor connected through HDMI port and disable primary monitor after boot. You can also add command for resolution which suits your external monitor but this is not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

You want to have a multi display android config.
cf:

[Configuring Display Settings](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/index.html)

[source TileUtils.java](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/src/com/android/settingslib/drawer/TileUtils.java)

[source SuggestionParser.java](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/src/com/android/settingslib/SuggestionParser.java)

[App Shortcuts](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/app-shortcuts.html)

[UI Shortcuts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html)

Comment: I don't want a multi display I just want to have a single display on external monitor with Specific key combination to project since my laptop's screen is damaged.

Comment: The android feature is named multi display, but you can configure only one of course

Comment: Agreed... but how?

Comment: Of course all this is reserved for very advanced users, but it is possible to map your specific projection keys (from your laptop keyboard) on intents for configuring your android. All documentation I mentioned allows to configure the android part. You still need to catch the keycodes for your <fn> keys and use them. Perhaps first try with some easier keys (as 'a', 'b', etc).

Comment: Fn+ F7 works for Windows but any other Fn + any other key does nothing for android. I can't even toggle bluetooth On and Off by Key combination.

Comment: I don't know the specifics for your laptop, but any key or key combinaison have a low level keycode (for ex at BIOS level). Linux kernel runs the same way and the keyboard driver provide a key code for any key combinaison. At now nothing should be triggered for handling this, but its up^to you to find which keycode is produced by the keyboard driver and then trap this and create an intent that could be broadcasted to a display management app.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what actions should I do as an end-user with the links given here...